# CSS Table Row Borders with Rounded Corners

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a table styled so that the corners are rounded and the rows (not cells) are solid lines. The problem that I'm having is:

```
tr {
     border-bottom: solid;
}
```

**DOES NOT WORK :(**

Here's my code so far: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindg/crz9hhkt/)

**How can I get continuous solid row borders for my table?**

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve solid lines by adding the rule:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

to the parent `<table>` element's CSS; this removes the spacing between the cells which resulted in the breaks in the borders of your original demo.

```css
table {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row one, cell one</td>
    <td>Row one, cell two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row two, cell one</td>
    <td>Row two, cell two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row three, cell one</td>
    <td>Row four, cell two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Updated [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/crz9hhkt/3/).

To allow the `<table>` to have curved borders, the only means by which I could make this work is to use a combination of:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Which unfortunately [also hides the border](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/crz9hhkt/8/), and:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
```

to emulate the (now-hidden) border.

```css
table {
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
}
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row one, cell one</td>
    <td>Row one, cell two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row two, cell one</td>
    <td>Row two, cell two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row three, cell one</td>
    <td>Row four, cell two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Updated [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/crz9hhkt/7/).

Comment: Look closely at the corners and you'll see gaps. I tried collapse a while back but I got this side-effect.

Comment: Check the updates to the answer, I think I've addressed that problem now?

Comment: @DavidThomas Please do you think you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/Yl5qIi

Answer (score 1):

Use `border-spacing: 0;` on the `table`. `border-spacing` specifies the distance between the borders of adjacent table cells.

```
table {
  ...
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Should work for you. Here's your revised fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/crz9hhkt/9/

Answer (score 0):

Put it like this maybe?

```
   table {
      background: red;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      -moz-border-radius: 6px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
      border-radius: 6px;
      border: solid;
    }
```

Comment: All that does is make the outer border more pronounced.